# Python tuple value separation in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary "inputlist". Each list has 3 tuple.
I want to put first value of first and second tuple in "mean1" variable and first value of third tuple in "mean2" variable.

Here is my code:

```
inputlist={
      1: {0: [(5.6, 3.6), (20.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0)]},
      2: {0: [(2.5, 0.5), (21.5, 0.5), (2.0, 0.0)],
          1: [(4.0, 0.0), (22.0, 0.0), (3.0, 0.0)]},
      3: {0: [(5.0, 0.0), (23.0, 0.0), (4.0, 0.0)],
          1: [(7.0, 0.0), (24.0, 0.0), (5.0, 0.0)]},
     }


for k1, v1 in inputlist.items():
    for (classValue, classModels) in v1.items():
        
         for i in range(len(classModels)):
            (mean1, stdev1) = classModels[i]
            (mean2, stdev2) = classModels[i]
            print(mean1)
            #print(mean2)
```

Output should be like:

```
Mean1:
5.6
20.0
2.5
21.5
4.0
22.0
5.0
23.0
7.0
24.0

Mean 2: 
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over inputlist and nested dicts and fetch targeted elements as follows and collect the result in individual list through `list.extend(list)`:

```
mean1 = []
mean2 = []

for k1, v1 in inputlist.items():
    for key, pairs in v1.items():
        lst = [x[0] for x in pairs]
        mean1.extend(lst[:-1])
        mean2.extend(lst[-1:])   

print(mean1)
print(mean2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple destructuring:

```py
inputlist={
      1: {0: [(5.6, 3.6), (20.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0)]},
      2: {0: [(2.5, 0.5), (21.5, 0.5), (2.0, 0.0)],
          1: [(4.0, 0.0), (22.0, 0.0), (3.0, 0.0)]},
      3: {0: [(5.0, 0.0), (23.0, 0.0), (4.0, 0.0)],
          1: [(7.0, 0.0), (24.0, 0.0), (5.0, 0.0)]},
}

print("Mean 1")
for _, d in inputlist.items():
    # Iterate over each list
    for _, lst in d.items():
        # Gets the first element of the first tuple
        # and the first element of the second tuple
        ((m1, _), (m2, _), (_, _)) = lst
        print(m1)
        print(m2)

print()
print("Mean 2")
for _, d in inputlist.items():
    # Iterate over each list
    for _, lst in d.items():
        # Gets the first element of the third tuple
        ((_, _), (_, _), (m, _)) = lst
        print(m)
```

Outputs

```
Mean1:
5.6
20.0
2.5
21.5
4.0
22.0
5.0
23.0
7.0
24.0

Mean 2: 
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what exactly you are asking. If you want to have the exact same output as the one in your question, then you will obviously need to loop twice over `inputlist`. So I assume your real question is how to do this:

> I want to put first value of first and second tuple in "mean1" variable and first value of third tuple in "mean2" variable.

If that's it, then `mean1` should be a tuple itself, since you want to put two floats in it. Something like this:

```
for k1, v1 in inputlist.items():
    for class_value, class_models in v1.items():
        for class_model in class_models:
            mean1 = (class_model[0][0], class_model[1][0])
            mean2 = class_model[2][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
""" Mean 1 """
for v in inputlist.values():
    for lst in v.values():
        print(lst[0][0])
        print(lst[1][0])

""" Mean 2 """
for v in inputlist.values():
    for lst in v.values():
        print(lst[2][0])
```

**output** for mean1

```
5.6
20.0
2.5
21.5
4.0
22.0
5.0
23.0
7.0
24.0
```

**output** for mean2

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

or **the messy way** ;)

```
m1, m2 = [], []
[[m1.append(ls[2][0]) or m2.append(ls[0][0]) or m2.append(ls[1][0]) for ls in v.values()] for v in inputlist.values()]
print(m1)
print(m2)
```